# add scroll to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jpanel

I have a problem adding scrollbar to my JPanel. This is my code but it isn't working! I need help!

---

```
public class DocumentView extends JPanel implements EventListener,MouseListener{

    public String name;
    private Document document;
    private Dimension dim;
    public DocumentView dv;

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(dv,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
        JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);


    public boolean selected = false;

    public DocumentView() {
        setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        this.add(scrollPane);
        setVisible(true);

        addMouseListener(this); //za kontra focus
    }  
}
```

### What is not working

it is supposed to be a document and you can add pages in it...So when I add more than 2 pages in one document it can not show all it just adds them but I can't see them...that is way I need scroll bar....not working , I mean it doesn't add scroll when I add more than 2 pages.

Comment: Is this your complete code?

Comment: no, but the rest of code is not important for scrollbar..it's just about adding new page into a document

Comment: Explain what you mean by not working.

Comment: it is supoused to be a document and you can add pages in it...So when i add more than 2 pages in one document it can not show all it just add them but i can't see them...that is way i need scroll bar....not working ,i mean it doesn't add scroll whan i add more than 2 pages.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @nikola3333 Take a look at my working example below.

Answer (score 2):

From your codes, you have another `DocumentView` panel within every `DocumentView` and you are adding the scrollpane to the instance `dv` instead of adding it to `DocumentView` itself.

If you want to add the scrollpane to `DocumentView` itself, it should probably be:

```
//Change "dv" to "this"
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(this, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, 
    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

---

If your intention is indeed to add the scrollpane to the instance `dv`, I didn't see you adding `dv` to your current JPanel.

I am not sure why you need another DocumentView instance within DocumentView. If you initialize dv in your constructor, beware of `StackOverFlowError`:

```
public DocumentView(){
    dv = new DocumentView();
    this.add(dv);  //Causes Stack Overflow error
}
```

Comment: i tried to change "dv" to "this" and the eclipse doesn't show me any errors, but when i run my program it break when i try to make new document

Comment: @nikola3333 I think you should discard `dv` entirely from your DocumentView class. As mentioned in my solution, if you try to instantiate DocumentView and add dv at the same time, stack overflow error will occur.

Comment: I understand it now and will delete this dv, but earlier today it was "this" indeed and it still didn't work...it just won't add scrollbar to my document

Comment: @nikola3333 What kind of component do you want to add into the panel with scrollpane? I see if I can write a simple working demo here.

Comment: another smaller panels..they represent pages in my document

Comment: @nikola3333 I see... give me a minute. I will write a demo here..

Comment: Ok, than You very much

Comment: @nikola3333 I've added a solution, do take a look.

Answer (score 2):

When adding a scrollbar, you need a panel and a scrollpane:

```
scrollPanel = new JPanel();
scrollPane = new JScrollPane(scrollPanel);
```

From now on, components added to the scollPanel will create a scrollbar(vertically and/or horizontally). The scrollbar will automatically adjust its height when new components are added because your scollPanel (JPanel) will have its preferredSize adjusted when new components are added/removed (if you use a layout). The layout manager will handle this for you.

[image]

A working example as follows:

```
class MainPanel extends JPanel{

    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JPanel scrollPanel;
    private JButton btnAddPage;

    public MainPanel(){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 140));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents(){
        scrollPanel = new JPanel();
        scrollPanel.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));       
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(scrollPanel);  //Let all scrollPanel has scroll bars

        btnAddPage = new JButton("Add New Page");
        btnAddPage.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                addPanel(new Page());
                scrollPanel.revalidate();
            }
        });     

        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(btnAddPage, BorderLayout.SOUTH);                
    }

    public void addPanel(JPanel pnl){
        scrollPanel.add(pnl);
    }
}
```

A Page class to simulate the pages you wanted to add:

```
class Page extends JPanel
{
    private static int idx = 1;
    private JLabel pageContent;
    public Page(){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 80));
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        pageContent = new JLabel("Page " + (idx++));
        add(pageContent);
    }
}
```

A runner class to drive the codes:

```
class ScrollPaneDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Scrollable Panel");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new MainPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);                 
            }   
        });     
    }
}
```

---

*PS: When dealing with scrollbars, you may have to carefully choose your layout the layout you choose will directly determine the dimension of your panel or even your added components, ultimately affecting the effectiveness of your scrollpane.*

Comment: Thank You very much @user3437460! I wasn't able to see this untill now.I really appreciate Your help!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

I'd like to give you some hints, so that you could solve your problem by yourself.

- The value of *dv* is empty when you it gets passed to the constructor of JScrollPane
- Take a look at the control hierarchy. You are creating a class for your DocumentView that will contain a JScrollPane that contains a DocumentView. I assume you want to make your DocumentView scrollable. Consider wrapping the whole control inside an independent JScrollPane (at a higher level).
- Tip: Try to set every instance variable (also called "fields") to private. Public fields are very rare.

**Regarding the control hierarchy**

There are two ways I'd like to recommend

1. Dedicated controls: You could create a dedidcated Document- and PageView class. DocumentView could inherit from JPanel and would contain the JScrollPane. The JScollPane wraps another JPanel with FlowLayout (vertical). Every time a new page is added to the DocumentView it will create a new instance of your PageView and add it to the JPanel that is wrapped inside your JScrollPane. The PageView simply displays the content.
2. Assuming you have infinite space: This is the way most Swing components are designed. Create a DocumentView that assumes that there is infinite space. Simply align every page vertically (one after another). Then you should overwrite the *getPreferredSize* method and return the size your control takes up. No you can simply wrap your whole DocumentView inside a JScrollPane.

Comment: Thank You for the tips, but could you explain the second one, i didn't get it

Comment: See the update. Hope it helps.